# JQuery Mobile - Everything Contained in New Div's

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

So for me, this is a completely new toy so I jumping and falling over hurdles reguarly (how else do you learn right?). The problem that I am struggling to work around is the way in which it seems to work.

The JQuery mobile API seems to get almost all of the elements within the page and put them inside a new div, this then prevents most of my elements from being inline as they were before. I have played around with the CSS to change the 'display' to inline for most of the elements that need changing but this is producing a difficult to work around solution and is just darn ugly. Also, when I then hover over the newly inline element, it goes back to being 'block'.

What am I missing?

Is there a way to achieve this non-hackedly?

Answer (score 0):

nest them in a div element with `style='display:inline !important;'`?

or

```
div[data-role='content']{
    display: inline !important;
}
```

in your .css-file.

But all this should result in a propably damn ugly pagelayout.